# Why is string is not getting replaced by capital letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have converted the string into an array and want to replace every first word with a capital letter for that I am using the replace method but not working

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].replace(arr[i][0], arr[i][0].toUpperCase())
  }
  
  let a = arr.join(' ');
  return a;
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: The `.replace()` function does not modify the original string; it returns a *new* string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed the code and it worked                                       
 function titleCase(str) {

  let arr= str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  console.log(arr);
  let narr=[];
  for(let i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
    narr.push(arr[i].replace(arr[i][0],arr[i][0].toUpperCase()));
  }
  let a = narr.join(' ');
  return a;
  }

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need that

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  var str = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    str[i] = arr[i].replace(arr[i][0], arr[i][0].toUpperCase());
  }
 
  return str.join(' ');
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: The OP isn't trying to capitalize every letter in the string, only the first letter of each word (titlecase)

Comment: I see let me update my code

Comment: @NickParsons updated sorry for the inconvenience